# Nsstring to decimal number and back

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to convert char to int and back with this:

```
NSString *input = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"א"];
int aVal = [input characterAtIndex:0];
char output = (char)aVal;
```

But in `output` i get : `\xd0` instead of `א` .

Any idea what can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is UniChar

```
 NSString *input = @"א";
 UniChar charec = [input characterAtIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

your character א is unicode, up to 32 bits

it's bigger than one char (8 bits), so you're reading just first 8 bits, and trying to represent them as a char